# ZipArchive::getFromName does not find filename

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

Any idea what I am doing wrong here? It keeps dying with 'bye bye'. There is an index.php file inside the zip archive.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($source);
$test = $zip->getFromName('index.php');
if(!$test) {
    die('bye bye');
} else {
    die($test);
}
```

Comment: Is this the same zip file as with your last question, where everything was contained within an `example/` subdirectory?

Comment: verify if the instruction $zip->open($source) returns TRUE. If it fails then you have problem with opening the archive so for sure also the getFromName will fail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the *first* thing you should do is ensure that you've opened it okay since that can fail as well:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$rc = $zip->open($source);
if ($rc === TRUE) {
    $test = $zip->getFromName('index.php');
    $zip->close();
    if(!$test) {
        die('bye bye');
    } else {
        die($test);
    }
} else {
    die("could not open: " . $rc);
}
```

Other than that, make sure you are *absolutely* certain that your file specification is correct. If necessary, you can use `getNameIndex` to enumerate the entries one at a time, printing out their names in the process, something like:

```
$zippy = new ZipArchive();
$zippy->open($source);
for ($i = 0; $i < $zippy->numFiles; $i++) {
    echo $zippy->getNameIndex($i) . '<br />';
}
$zippy->close();
```

And I'm *assuming* that I would be wasting my time telling you to check the value of `$source`. You may want to check, just in case.

Comment: Snap! Did exactly that with getNameIndex. Worked out that I am idiot. The zip file I had prepared had the folder structure in it because I forgot to jsut select all my individual files and compress them together. So I needed to use $zip->getFromName("example/index.php"); Now I've compressed the files correctly. That took me way too long to work out. Also regarding the check, I have it in the script but didn't put it here sorry. Good to know for anyone else who comes across this question.

Comment: My archive seemed use backslashes. folder\file.csv. Thanks to your second code block I was able to figure that out. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As at PHP 8 this can also occur if you are busy building an archive and you try and use getFromName() on a valid file in the archive. I got false no matter what I tried.

eg.

```
1 create archive
2 ...add things
3 archive->getFromName("valid/archive/file/path/and/name")
```

Step 3 returns false every time.

However

```
1 create archive
2 ...add things
A close archive
B re-open archive
3 archive->getFromName("valid/archive/file/path/and/name")
```

Step 3 now returns the contents of the file as expected.

So inserting steps A and B made getFromName() work as expected.

Hope this helps someone not waste as much time as I just did :(

Comment: You're an angel! Closing the zip file and opening again works :)